# Not able to set ContainSize of my ScrollView through Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am adding more than 8-9 controls in my `ScrollView` but I am not able to set `ContaintSize` of that `ScrollView` so that I can able to scroll and view all controlls.

I HAVE SET below constrains to my scrollview and add some controls into my scroll view with the help of contain view.

`Scrollview.top` respect to his superview

`Scrollview.bottom` respect to his superview

`Scrollview.leading` respect to his superview

`Scrollview.trailling` reapect to his superview

Than I have added `UIView` as contain view and set all constrain respect to scrollview.

Than added all controls into view but still its not scrolling as  expected.

By below code I am able to set containview but its ststic one and cant assume that 1000 is my contanent height.

`Scrollview.contentsize = CGSizeMake (Scrollview.frame.size.width,1000);`

Above part is static as I have many lable with multiple line in it.

All data is dynamic comes from server si cant set it static.

Can any one help me out how to set `autolayout` of scrollview so I can get dynamic content size?

Edit: some time I am getting autolayout error into storyboard like below.

> Scrollview has ambiguous scrollable content height

An while i reslove conflicts its not showing proper scrollview in my screen.

Comment: what `8-9 controls` you have added just clarify and be specific.

Comment: I am adding ImageView and 7-8 labels in my scrollview

Comment: @BhaviDev as per @L_Sonic suggested link for setting `ContaintSize` with Autolayout + storyboard please go through that link.

Comment: tell us the hierarchy view > scrollView > then ?.

Comment: If you use Auto Layout then no need to set content size.

Comment: Hierarchy is Self.view>scrollview>containview>all controls (imageview,labels).

Comment: @CodeChanger I have already go through that link and follow the same steps as mention there bilut still something is missing thats why my scrollview not scrolling.

Comment: @BhaviDev your problem is solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced the same issue recently. I'm sure that you did your research but here is the guide I used, nonetheless.

https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Also if you have many labels it would be good consider using a 'UITableView' or a 'UIStackView'.

**Edit**

Make sure you center the scroll view vertically and horizontally in respect to its container.

Comment: sharing the specific point with code here leads the proper response to a ques, links may cause uncertainty.

Comment: I have already seen this link and also followed same steps that thay mention to do vut no luck to scroll my scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your issue you forgot to set the `height` constraint of your `contentView`, just try by setting it.

No need to set the fix height of `scrollView's` `contentSize`, please see the below code.

```
self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, contentView.frame.origin.y + contentView.frame.size.height + 10);
```

**Note:** you need to add `height` and `width` constraint of `contentView` if you need scroll according to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define constraints for the scroll view like this..

ScrollView :
top ,left , bottom, right pinned to superview.

ContainerView:

top, left , bottom , right pinned to scroll view
width pinned to main view

And make sure that every subview inside the container view should have constraints in such a way that it should define the height of container view.